# How Can i set same position of widgets for different device?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

> > Hi to Everyone. I am setting position of icon widget. But it is
> > changing on different device. How can i fix it? thanks in advance.

**> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
                 [for example][1]







    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:country_icons/country_icons.dart';
    
    class E_Takvim_Container extends StatefulWidget {
      const E_Takvim_Container({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _E_Takvim_ContainerState createState() => _E_Takvim_ContainerState();
    }
    
    class _E_Takvim_ContainerState extends State<E_Takvim_Container> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Takvim"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          ),
          body: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: Row(
                      
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 30,
                          height: 30,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'icons/flags/png/de.png',
                                  package: 'country_icons',
                                ),
                              ),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(300, 900))),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Tüketici Fiyat Endeksi",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:100.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIzkv.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code example, you can use `Expanded` for your `TextView` widget.

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Text(
     "Tüketici Fiyat Endeksi",
     style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 17),
   ),
)
```

If you want to get the same results at different screen resolutions, (for example: size of widgets or font sizes) You can take a look at the package: [ScreenUtils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)